# How do you get and set a session variable?

Tags: php, sql, session-variables

I want to be able to take the value from `($_SESSION['username']))`, that I call at the top of page, and use it as a variable so that I can use the value `username` in an SQL query statement.

I've tried:

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
```

but when I use `var_dump($user)` it's NULL. I've tried casting it to a `strval` but it's still empty.

How can I add `username` to a variable?

Here is the session code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_SESSION['first_name']&&($_SESSION['username']))

echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['first_name']."<br><a href='logged_out.php'>log out</a>";

else
die("You must be logged in. Click <a href='login/login_page.php'>here</a> to log   
in.");

?>
```

Comment: Uhm... is `$_SESSION['username']` actually set?

Comment: Need some code here, what you've tried should work. (Assuming `$_SESSION['username']` is actually not null)

Comment: your code doesn't show that you've set it anywhere. I would look there for the cause of the problem.

Comment: code added. If I echo $_SESSION['username']; it echoes out the value, but can't seem to add it to variable

Comment: need some more. no obvious (relevant) bugs in that code.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have session_start(); at the top of your php script on every page you want to use the session variable

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['username'] = bob;
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
//retrieve session data
$username_from_session = $_SESSION['username'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you feel like this answered your question, please consider marking the answer above as the accepted answer by clicking the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Just like [Garbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276220/garbit) said. You can't use $_Session[''] before you have used session_start somewhere in the document. I also recommend that you start each session in the header. Why you may ask; it comes to the fact that the code in the header is always being run at first, just as if you linked a JavaScript document at the bottom of the page, then it would load after everything else. (Mixing up client side and server side are we? Not really, they work the same way, just that the server outputs server side code and the web browser parses the client side code)